# How to align a text vertically in a div while inside another div?

Tags: css, css-float, vertical-alignment

I am trying to vertically align a text inside a div. I have create a Fiddle of my current problem.

you can view my code on this link
http://jsfiddle.net/NSvGc/

Here in my current code

```
<div style="display: block; width: 500px; border: 1px dashed #C0C0C0; margin: 0 auto; padding: 5px;">
<div style="display: inline-block; width: 300px; height: 100%; vertical-align: middle;"
    ><b>Text</b>
    </div>
    <div style="display: inline-block;">
        <div style="display:block; width: 180px;" >
            <input type="text" value="2013-01-01 12:45 PM" name="triggerOn[]" id="triggerOn_'+ v.call_code_id +'" readonly="readonly" style="width: 175px;"></div>
        <div style="display:block; margin: 5px;"><input type="checkbox" id="isAppointment" name="isAppointment" value="1" /> Make an appointment.</div>
</div>
</div>
```

What do I need to do is to vertically align the word "Text"

The problem here is the the inner div is not 100% in height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took the liberty of moving some of the CSS inside your HTML into the CSS area. On your web page you should probably put it in `<style>` tags instead of hard coded into each element to make it readable.

I changed your HTML structure because yours was very... interesting... I formatted it like it should appear: one container containing everything -> two areas for right and left. From what you had it seemed that this is a one time fix and you're not going to need very much flexibility so I came up with [this hard coded solution](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/NSvGc/9/). It involves `float`ing the right content and absolutely positioning the left content to make it centered. If you have larger content than just "Text" you will need to adjust the `top` value for that class\

Here is my edited HTML

```
<div class='container'>
<b class='text'>Text</b>
    <div class='appointment'>
        <input type="text" value="2013-01-01 12:45 PM" name="triggerOn[]" id="triggerOn_'+ v.call_code_id +'" readonly="readonly" style="width: 175px;">
        </br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="isAppointment" name="isAppointment" value="1" />
        <div id='spacing'></div>Make an appointment.</div>
</div>
```

and my edited CSS (separate, not in the tags)

```
.container {
    display: block;
    width: 500px;
    height:70px;
    border: 1px dashed #C0C0C0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 5px; 
}
.appointment {
    display: inline-block;
    float:right;
}
.text {
    position:absolute;
    top:35px;
    margin-left:15px;
}
#spacing {
    width:10px;
    height:2px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

**Edit:**

Since you want the left area perfectly vertically centered, I changed the structure of the HTML and changed the CSS to suit it, but it is really impossible without some javascript aid. I used jQuery to center each perfectly. Another solution would be to use Flexbox, but I opted for the jQuery route. [Here is the new dynamic solution](http://jsfiddle.net/NSvGc/15/)

Here is my updated HTML

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="bubble-left">
          <b class='text'>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</b>
      </div>
    <div class='bubble-right'>
        <div class='appointment'>
        <input type="text" value="2013-01-01 12:45 PM" name="triggerOn[]" id="triggerOn_'+ v.call_code_id +'" readonly="readonly" style="width: 175px;"></br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="isAppointment" name="isAppointment" value="1" /><div id='spacing'></div>Make an appointment.</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    width: 500px; 
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px dashed #C0C0C0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 5px;
}
.bubble-left { 
    position: absolute; 
    left: 5px; 
    top: 0; 
    width: 300px; 
    height: 100%; 
    display: table; 
}

.bubble-left b {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle; 
    text-align: center; 
}

.bubble-right {
    position: absolute; 
    padding-top:5px;
    right: 50px; 
    top: 40%; 
    width: 135px; 
    height: 30px; 
    display: table; 
}
#spacing {
    width:10px;
    height:2px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

and added javascript

```
var biggestHeight = "0";
// Loop through elements children to find & set the biggest height
$(".container *").each(function(){
 // If this elements height is bigger than the biggestHeight
 if ($(this).height() > biggestHeight ) {
   // Set the biggestHeight to this Height
   biggestHeight = $(this).height();
 }
});

// Set the container height
$(".container").height(biggestHeight);

//position right content verically
$('.bubble-right').css('top', $('.bubble-right').parent().height()/2 - $('.bubble-right').height()/2);
```

Comment: Thank you. this code will work only if you know the length of the text so you can hard code the absolute values.But in my case i don't know the length of the text. So if I have a 1 paragraph long text I want the text to be aligned in the middle and also the check-box/date to be align in the middle.

Comment: You should say so in the question next time then. Check my update for an updated solution

Comment: @Mike did either of our solutions meet your needs?

Answer (score 1):

If it were me, I would use a table like this: [JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/NSvGc/11/)

I added in a red border for style testing.

```
<table style="text-align: left; width: 500px; height: 100px; border: 1px dashed black; padding: 10px;" border="0"
 cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="vertical-align: bottom; font-size: 20px;">Text!</td>
      <td style="vertical-align: top; width: 150px;">

          <div style="display: inline-block;">

        <div style="display:block; width: 180px;" >

            <input type="text" value="2013-01-01 12:45 PM" name="triggerOn[]" id="triggerOn_'+ v.call_code_id +'" readonly="readonly" style="width: 175px;">
            </div>

            <div style="display:block; margin: 5px;">
                <input type="checkbox" id="isAppointment" name="isAppointment" value="1" /> Make an appointment.
            </div>

        </div></div>

        </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Well, with a table cell you can vertical-align either to top, middle, or bottom. And do horizontal align with text-align to left, center, or right. So, to fix that, just change the td tag to `<td style="vertical-align: middle;"`

Comment: I have used tables for this. I was trying to stay away from tables but that did not work here